# Get Class properties and values using Typescript reflection

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

Say I have a class

```
Class A {}
```

And would like to iterate through `Class A` properties (checking for null values) only knowing that `Class A` will have properties but might vary in property names and number of properties (e.g.)

```
Class A {
  A: string;
  B: string;
}
```

or

```
Class A {
  B: string;
  C: string;
  D: string;
}
```

Is there a way I can iterate through `Class A` properties and check if the values are null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## At Runtime

Only if you explicitly assign them.

```
class A {
  B: string | null = null;
  C: string | null = null;
  D: string | null = null;
}
const a = new A();
for (let key in a) {
  if (a[key] == null) {
    console.log('key is null:', key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript class do not exist at run time as it is transpiled down to plain old JavaScript. You can get the properties of an instance of an Object

```js
const a = { prop1: null, prop2: 'hello', prop3: 1 };

const nullProps = obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(prop => obj[prop] === null);

console.log(nullProps(a));
```