# Get class attributes from class defintion

Tags: typescript, reflection

I would like to get a list of attributes from the class itself (not a class instance)

```
class A { a:string; b:string; }
getAttributes(A); // returns ['a', 'b']
```

Is this possible in typescript ?

Comment: I think your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421302/get-class-properties-and-values-using-typescript-reflection

Comment: @SunnyZarin no, I have seen this post, and the response uses a class instance, I would like to use the classe itself

Comment: So just create an instance? `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new A);`

Comment: He wants to do it with the Class itself not an instance. I think that would not be that straightforward because typescript is transpiled to JavaScript. So when the code actually runs the type information will be gone. I am not sure but I doubt that a simple class declaration that is not used will make it to the final js output.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković don't want to, because the constructor might have some logic that I dont want to trigger

Comment: @SunnyZarin thats my fear but I'm open to any solution, including reading d.ts file, activationg some sort of ts option ...